# MFMailComposeViewController Console Log "...is not a valid email address"

Tags: validation, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

When sending an email with in invalid email addy I get this "...is not a valid email address" in the console log.

This is ok and I get why it is happening.

What I want to know is.. where is this NSLog statement coming from and can I access it?

Somewhere in the MFCVController or delegate the framework is checking if the email is valid or not and then logging "...is not a valid email address" accordingly.

I want to access this call and check for the same thing and create an alertView.

Before commenting here are some things I already know...
I know how to create alertViews.
I know about and have read other posts users have created with code that checks strings for invalid email addresses.

Thanks for helping!

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Here is a helpful insight, It literally happens in here: Reference the NSLog with the condole printout.

```
        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {   NSLog(@"Log 1");

        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailer setSubject:@"Checklist Complete"];
        NSLog(@"Log 2");
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:emailAddress];
        NSLog(@"Log 3");
        [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        NSLog(@"Log 4");
        NSString *emailBody = emailBodyContents;
        NSLog(@"Log 5");
        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        NSLog(@"Log 6");
        //For iPad
        //mailer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
        [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"Log 7");

    }
```

Console.

```
2014-01-15 21:11:30.581 AppTemplate[1018:70b] Log 1
2014-01-15 21:11:30.584 AppTemplate[1018:70b] Log 2
2014-01-15 21:11:30.585 AppTemplate[1018:70b] Log 3
2014-01-15 21:11:30.585 AppTemplate[1018:70b] (null) is not a valid email address.
2014-01-15 21:11:30.586 AppTemplate[1018:70b] Log 4
2014-01-15 21:11:30.586 AppTemplate[1018:70b] Log 5
2014-01-15 21:11:30.587 AppTemplate[1018:70b] Log 6
2014-01-15 21:11:30.588 AppTemplate[1018:70b] Log 7
```

And this is the documentation I found in Xcode

```
- (void)setToRecipients:(NSArray *)toRecipients __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0)
/*!
@method     setCcRecipients:
@abstract   This method sets the CC header for the email message to the specified email addresses.
@discussion This method will set the CC header for the email message.  This should be called prior to display.
            </p>Recipient addresses should be specified as per RFC5322.
            </p>After the view has been presented to the user, this method will no longer change the value.
@param      ccRecipients  A NSArray of NSString instances specifying the email addresses of recipients.
```

*/

Comment: You can search the entire workspace in xcode with exact match on log message. That way you can may be extend it for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your tip.  Unfortunately I have done that and the search turned up empty. I've even examined all the "NSLog"'s that are in my workspace. - Nothing. Question, and this is taking it a step further... I have also noticed that "NSLog"'s found in Apple's Default .h files are not found in this search... could this NSLog be found in somewhere in an apple premade .h, if so, where?

Comment: What is MFCVController? I cannot find any info on it online. Is that something you wrote?

Comment: Sorry, it is short for MFMailComposeViewController. This is an apple produced controller.

Comment: So the MFMailComposeVC does not have an error message by itself. See my answer.

Comment: @ xoail This question is still unresolved. Anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the delete and detect if an error occurred like this:

```
- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

// Close the Mail Interface
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I already have this implemented. Everything works perfectly. I just want to know where this NSLog is coming from.  I never wrote it and yet after I got everything hooked up it's logging it.